# Export variable label for SPSS with haven

Tags: r, spss, r-haven

I would like to export a data set I work on in `R` for my colleagues to use in `SPSS`. When I export the data set I would like to include variable labels (i.e. the column below), I am *not* asking about value labels which describe the levels of the variable:

[image: Variable label]

Is there an option in `haven` that allows me to set this variable label?

I have searched the documentation and found only functions to set value labels. I notice `haven` is a wrapper for [`ReadStat`](https://github.com/WizardMac/ReadStat) which seems to support variable labels. In the [`ReadStat` documentation](https://github.com/WizardMac/ReadStat#command-line-usage-with-csv-input) a variable label (`Citizenship of respondent`) can be seen in the chunk below:

```
{
    "type": "SPSS",
    "variables": [
        {
            "type": "NUMERIC",
            "name": "citizenship",
            "label": "Citizenship of respondent",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "code": 1,
                    "label": "Afghanistan"
                },
...
```

My understanding of `C++` is unfortunately not sophisticated enough to understand how `haven` works under the hood, so any suggestions are very welcome.

I *have* found a workaround, which involves manually setting the variable label by use of attributes. Consider the example below, using a teaching data set from the [UK Data Service](https://discover.ukdataservice.ac.uk/catalogue/?sn=7912&type=Data%20catalogue):

```
# install.packages("tidyverse")
library("tidyverse")

tmp    = tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
tmpdir = tempdir()

download.file(
  "http://ws.ukdataservice.ac.uk/REST/Download/Download/DSO/7912spss_e5b795672124e5b409e4a53c1a06fb9e.zip",
  destfile = tmp
)
unzip(tmp, exdir = tmpdir)

tmpdir = paste0(tmpdir, "/UKDA-7912-spss/spss/spss19/")
file   = paste0(tmpdir, list.files(tmpdir))

dat = haven::read_sav(file)

str(dat)

# Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 22428 obs. of  14 variables:
#  $ CASENEW : atomic  1 2 3 5 5 6 6 7 8 9 ...
#   ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "New random ID number"
#   ..- attr(*, "format.spss")= chr "F8.2"
#   ..- attr(*, "display_width")= int 10
# ...
```

I can therefore change the variable label with:

```
attr(dat$CASENEW, "label") = "Foo"
attr(dat$CASENEW, "label")
# "Foo"
```

Which, when I write to a new `.sav` file, does indeed open as intended in `SPSS`. My question is, is there a native way to do this in `haven`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hadley's answer:

Just set the attributes— Hadley Wickham (@hadleywickham) [October 27, 2017](https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/923884783515643904?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

So there you have it: the canonical `haven` answer is just to set the attributes.